# Access to Anonymous Function

Tags: scala

Let's say I have a type:

```
type State[S, +A] = S => (A,S)
```

and a function:

```
def foo(): State[Obj, (x, y)]
```

If I call this function:

`val result = foo() // result is an anonymous function: Obj => ((x, y), Obj)`

How can I access the `Obj` and `(x, y)` values?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get concrete values for `(x, y)` and the final state of `Obj`, you will need to pass an initial value of `Obj` into your function. Something like:

```
val (coords, finalObj) = foo().run(initObj)
```

(I may be misremembering the name of the `run` method on the scalaz state monad).

**UPDATE**

Actually, I think it is just `apply`, so `foo()(initObj)` would work (although I'd probably get rid of the unneeded parentheses on the definition of `foo`, reducing the final call to just `foo(initObj)`).

Comment: Since `State` is defined above as a function, you call `apply`, not `run`.

Comment: When I pass an initObj, I get the `initObj` state, not the `finalObj`. Could you please see my source on line 48? - https://github.com/kman007us/side-work/blob/master/CandyMachine/CandyMachine.scala

Comment: [Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6987251) where I have tried to modify your source to work using the State monad you define in the code. In particular, look at how `go` works. NB: this is very rough and ready, just trying to convey the general idea.

Comment: @Shadowlands, could you please tell me why you're caling `go(xs)(m)`, as well as why you changed the function signature of `go`? Please note that I don't fully understand Monads.

Comment: The call to `go(inputs)` returns a `State[Machine, (Int,Int)]`, which is a function from (an initial) `Machine` to a (final) `(Machine, (Int, Int))` pair. As such, it doesn't take in a `Machine` itself. The starting `Machine` is instead passed in to this generated function.